# Missing Password check

Tags: php, mysql, database, md5, verification

I am using the code below, it checks for empty fields and verifies email, but even if the password is correct it won't login.  the password has been inserted with md5 protection, below is the code.

PHP:

```
      session_start(); 

      //Checks if there is a login cookie

      if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site']))


     //if there is, it logs you in and directes you to the members page

     { 
       $email = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 

        $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];

           $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = '$email'")or              die(mysql_error());

        while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))  

        {

           if ($pass != $info['password']) 

                    {

                          }

           else

             {

               header("Location: home.php");



               }

            }

        }


     //if the login form is submitted 

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if form has been submitted



     // makes sure they filled it in

           if(!$_POST['email'] | !$_POST['password']) {

           die('You did not fill in a required field.');

          }

          // checks it against the database



           if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

             $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);

          }

          $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."'")or die(mysql_error());



        //Gives error if user dosen't exist

     $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);

     if ($check2 == 0) {

               die('That user does not exist in our database. <a href=add.php>Click Here to Register</a>');

            }

            while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))  

        {

         $_POST['password'] = stripslashes($_POST['password']);

     $info['password'] = stripslashes($info['password']);

      $_POST['password'] = md5($_POST['password']);



     //gives error if the password is wrong

        if ($_POST['password'] != $info['password']) {

          die('Incorrect password, please try again.');

        }

         else 

        { 


              // if login is ok then we add a cookie 

           $_POST['email'] = stripslashes($_POST['email']); 

           $hour = time() + 3600; 

              setcookie(ID_my_site, $_POST['email'], $hour); 

              setcookie(Key_my_site, $_POST['password'], $hour);     



                //then redirect them to the members area 

              header("Location: home.php"); 

          } 

           } 

        } 

     else 

  {  



      // if they are not logged in 



     <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post"> 

      <table border="0"> 

    <tr><td colspan=2><h1>Login</h1></td></tr> 

    <tr><td>email:</td><td> 

    <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="40"> 

     </td></tr> 

       <tr><td>Password:</td><td> 

    <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="50"> 

    </td></tr> 

     <tr><td colspan="2" align="right"> 

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"> 

    </td></tr> 

  </table> 

   </form>
```

}

Here is the registration code:

PHP:

```
       // here we encrypt the password and add slashes if needed
        $_POST['password'] = md5($_POST['password']);
         if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
      $_POST['password'] = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);
     $_POST['email'] = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']);
      $_POST['full_name'] = mysql_escape_string($_POST['full_name']);
     $_POST['user_url'] = mysql_escape_string($_POST['user_url']);
        }


        // now we insert it into the database
    $insert = "INSERT INTO accounts (Uniquer, Full_name, Email, Password, User_url)
  VALUES ('".$uniquer."','".$_POST['full_name']."', '".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['password']."', '".$_POST['user_url']."')";
    $add_member = mysql_query($insert);
```

After using ini_set function i got to see the error, i am getting this message but not sure what it means:

```
There are the lines where the errors are at: 

                if ($pass != $info['password'])
```

and this line

```
                        if ($_POST['password'] != $info['password']) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, if you notice in the queries it says SELECT *, instead i tried SELECT email, password.

Comment: That shouldn't have made any difference at all.

Comment: True.  But not sure why it worked, i don't recall changing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The one thing I can see is that you use `stripslashes` on the posted password (the non-md5 version) but use it on the md5 version for the stored password.

You shouldn't really need to use `stripslashes` on the password in the database, since no password should be stored with slashed to begin with.

What happens if you change:

```
$_POST['password'] = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
$info['password'] = stripslashes($info['password']);
$_POST['password'] = md5($_POST['password']);
```

To:

```
$_POST['password'] = md5($_POST['password']);
$_POST['password'] = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
$info['password'] = stripslashes($info['password']);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I made the change, i still can't get through.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the db field with `$info['password']`, but the database field is actually `Password` **with a capital P**.

You are calling `mysql_escape_string` to store the data in the db, and the calling `stripslashes` on the submitted login form.  Perhaps they are doing different things to the password.  A few more things to think about:

- If you md5 a password to store it in the db, you **don't** need to call `stripslashes` or `mysql_escape_string` on it.  It has already been converted into only alphanumeric characters.
- `mysql_escape_string` is deprecated.
- Instead of escaping the email field, you may be better validating it's format.

After inserting a new registration, manually md5 the used password, then check that value against the one stored in the db.  You may find that they are different.

Comment: Thanks JMC.  I tested, i echoed the password being typed and the one in the database, they match with the md5.  I am still trying to find it.  thanks anyways.

Comment: If you can sort of help me with this i will be grateful.  I have come to the conclusion that the issue might be with the $info['password'], i echoed it but nothing shows....

Comment: After printing the error on screen i get the following message:   Notice: Undefined index: password in /var/www/domain.com/htdocs/login.php on line 103 Notice: Use of undefined constant password - assumed 'password' in /var/www/domain.com/htdocs/login.php on line 11

Comment: @AAA The database field is capitalized "Password" and you are using ` $info['password'] ` to access it!

Comment: i have no idea why but it still works without having to change it. lol crazy code.

Answer (score 0):

You asked a similar question some time ago with comepletely different code, so I'm assuming it's more of a database problem now.

Does your password field allow 32 characters for the md5 hash? A too short password field will truncate md5 hash, thus always failing login.

Comment: Hey, yeah i am using another code so reposted here.  The password maxlength is set to 50.

Comment: And the password field in the db is set to varchar(40)

Comment: What is the purpose of the info['password']; ?

Comment: its your code... but it looks to me like $info['password'] is the hash of the password stored in the db to compare against

Comment: yeah i am not sure i am playing around with it but i still can't find what the hell is wrong.

Comment: if all else fails go back to basics..remove the md5 stuff from your scripts and database, and test on plain text passwords. Add lots of debug information.

Comment: @AAA Can you paste in the code you use to store a registration in the db?

Comment: I changed a whole lot, for some reason it works.  it should be stable as long as it is detecing, right?